# .htaccess file mod_rewrite redirecting to parent directory instead of sub-directory when file names are same in both directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am accessing the root directory via `domain-A.com` and a sub-directory via `domain-B.com`

All redirects are working properly for `domain-B.com` except those that are having `same names` for instance if root directory contains a file called `abc.html` and subdirectory also contains the file `abc.html` in that case accessing `domain-B.com/abc.html` shows the contents of `domain-A.com/abc.html` but the url remains the same i.e. `domain-B.com/abc.html`

I would like to know how can this be resolved.
I am using Ubuntu and these are the settings that I have made for various file

I have already enabled mod_rewrite using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

**.htaccess - 
path /var/www/html**

```
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on

# Change domain.com to be your primary main domain. http://domain-b.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain-b.com$

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you want to redirect request to.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain-b/

# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you want to use for your primary domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain-b/$1 [L]

# Change domain.com to be your primary domain again.
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain-b.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain-b/index.html [L]
```

**httpd.conf - 
Path /etc/apache2/conf-available**

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

**000-default.conf - 
Path /etc/apache2/sites-available**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**000-default.conf - 
Path /etc/apache2/sites-enabled**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with these 2 conditions:

```
# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Which means if a file or directory exists in site root dir then don't rewrite to sub-directory.

Just change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Change domain.com to be your primary domain again.
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-b\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ domain-b/index.html [L]

# Change domain.com to be your primary main domain. http://domain-b.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-b\.com$ [NC]
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you want to redirect request to.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain-b/ [NC]
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you want to use for your primary domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain-b/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it worked but I had to change the domain-b/index.html file to domain-b/index.php I do not understand the reason behind this behaviour because we have this RewriteRule ^/?$ domain-b/index.html [L] which should take the user to index.html file but it kept on looking for domain-b/index.php.